# FragmentManager крашится при вызове Replace

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Приветствую.
Есть у меня Активити и несколько фрагментов. Необходимо при клике элемент в Navigation Drawer'е заменить фрагмент в контейнере. Однако после выполнения следующего кода, приложение крашится.
Прилагаю код:

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new MainFragment();
                break;
            }
            if (fragment != null) {

                Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;
                var transaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);
                transaction.Commit();

                mDrawerList.SetItemChecked (position, true);
                SetTitle (mScreenTitles [position]);
                mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer (mDrawerList);
            } else {
                Log.Error (this.Class.Name, "Error, fragment not created");
            }
```

Содержание ошибки:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at --- End of managed
>   exception stack trace ---   at java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)   at
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)   at at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   at ... 1 more   at Caused by:
>   md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Android.OS.BaseBundle'
>   from assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'.   at
>   Android.Views.View.n_OnSaveInstanceState (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d23da369/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:14822
>   at at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   object.e0a03ea8-44fe-4482-bf92-bc99edac0352 (intptr,intptr)    at at
>   md5d7f0962782a324dbc9992a12c8322ca0.PagerSlidingTabStrip.n_onSaveInstanceState(Native
>   Method)   at at
>   md5d7f0962782a324dbc9992a12c8322ca0.PagerSlidingTabStrip.onSaveInstanceState(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:86)
>   at at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:13550)
>   at at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2859) 
>   at at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865) 
>   at at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:13533)   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentViewState(FragmentManager.java:1639)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1023)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1233)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:696)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
>   at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)   at at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)   at at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)   at ... 4
>   more

Answer (score 1):

Если посмотреть на ошибку:

```
Could not load type 'Android.OS.BaseBundle' from
```

То выходит система не находит этого самого бандла, который юзается для передачи агрументов во фрагмент (ну как и в интенте в активити). Я не из мира С, но посоветовал бы попробовать скомпилить под меньший АПИ левел, там вижу под 5.1 компилится, попробуйте тупо под 15й АПИ, ведро 4.0. Просто 5.1 относительно недавно вышел, может там грабли какие.

Comment: Это C#. Пишу под xamarin.android.